# what is wrong with the syntax that does not give me an outfile?

Tags: perl

I dont know what exactly is wrong but everytime I execute this script i keep getting "No such file or directory at ./reprioritize line 35,  line 1".

here is my script that is having an issue:

```
my $newresult = "home/user/newresults_percengtage_vs_pn";

sub pushval
        {
        my @fields = @_;
        open OUTFILE, ">$newresult/fixedhomdata_030716-031316.csv" or die $!;   #line 35
        while(<OUTFILE>)
        {
                if($fields[5] >= 13)
                {
                        print OUTFILE "$fields[0]", "$fields[1]","$fields[2]","$fields[3]","$fields[4]","$fields[5]", "0";
                }
                elsif($fields[5] < 13 && $fields[5] > 1)
                {
                        print OUTFILE "$fields[0]", "$fields[1]","$fields[2]","$fields[3]","$fields[4]","$fields[5]", "1";
                }
                elsif($fields[5] <= 1)
                {
                        print OUTFILE "$fields[0]", "$fields[1]","$fields[2]","$fields[3]","$fields[4]","$fields[5]", "2";
                }
        }
        close (OUTFILE);
```

Comment: `home/user/newresults_percengtage_vs_pn` is a relative path; unless you run your script from `/`, it's not the same as `/home/user/newresults_percengtage_vs_pn`.

Comment: how would i be able to outfile it to that specific location then?

Comment: Plus you are opening the file for writing and then loop over the filehandle as if you were reading from it. I suggest _either -- or_.

Comment: @m.lochhead by adding the missing `/` maybe?

Comment: @sidyll it didnt work :/

Comment: @PerlDog what do you mean by either -- or ?

Comment: the probelm is to read in a file and then output a file. above the "sub pushval" i have the file being read into to program. this function is to take that data from the file and outfile a new file. thats where the "$fields" come from.

Comment: _Either/or_ means: _either_ you open the file for reading and iterate over the filehandle _or_ you open the file for writing and then iterate over your data structure and write to the file. You can do both r/w on the same filehandle but not the way you opened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Perl's tutorial on opening files](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Opening-Text-Files).

I simplify it a bit. There are basically three modes: open for **reading**, open for **writing**, and open for **appending**.

#### Reading

Opening for **reading** is indicated by either a `<` preceeding the filename or on its own, as a separate parameter to the `open()` call (preferred), i.e.:

```
my $fh = undef;
my $filename = 'fixedhomdata_030716-031316.csv';
open($fh, "<$filename") or die $!;      # bad   
open($fh, '<', $filename) or die $!;    # good
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {             # read one line from filehandle $fh
   ...
}
close($fh);
```

When you open the file this way, *it must exist*, else you get your error (`No such file or directory at ...`).

#### Writing

Opening for **writing** is indicated by a `>`, i.e.:

```
open($fh, ">$filename") or die $!;      # bad   
open($fh, '>', $filename) or die $!;    # good
print $fh "some text\n";                # write to filehandle $fh
print $fh "more text\n";                # write to filehandle $fh
...
close($fh);
```

When you open the file this way, it is truncated (cleared) and overwritten if it existed. If it did not exist, it will get created.

#### Appending

Opening for **appending** is indicated by a `>>`, i.e.:

```
open($fh, ">>$filename") or die $!;     # bad   
open($fh, '>>', $filename) or die $!;   # good
print $fh "some text\n";                # append to filehandle $fh
print $fh "more text\n";                # append to filehandle $fh
...
close($fh);
```

When you open the file this way and it existed, then the new lines will be appended to the file, i.e. nothing is lost. If the file did not
exist, it will be created (as if only `>` had been given).

Your error message doesn't match your code. You opened the file for writing (`>`) but got `doesn't exist`, which indicates that you actually opened it for reading.

This *might* have happened because you use OUTPUT as a filehandle instead of a scoped variable, e.g. `$fh`. OUTPUT is a *global* filehandle, i.e. if you open a file this way, then all of your code (no matter which function in) can use OUTPUT. Don't do that. From the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> An older style is to use a bareword as the filehandle, as
>
> ```
>     open(FH, "<", "input.txt")
>        or die "cannot open < input.txt: $!";
> ```
>
> Then you can use FH as the filehandle, in close FH and  and so on.
>   Note that it's a global variable, ***so this form is not recommended
>   in new code.***

To summarize:

- use scoped variables as filehandles (`$fh` instead of `OUTPUT`)
- open your file in the right mode (`>` vs. `<`)
- always use three-argument open (`open($fh, $mode, $filename)` vs. `open($fh, "$mode$filename")`

Comment: thank you so much for clarifying it! it fixed the problem i was having.

Answer (score 0):

The comments explain that your two issues with the snippet are

1. The missing leading '/' in the $newresult declaration
2. You are treating your filehandle as both a read and a write.

The first is easy to fix. The second is not as easy to fix properly with knowing the rest of the script. I am making an assumption that pushval is called once per record in a Array of Arrays(?). This snippet below should get the result you want, but there is likely a better way of doing it.

```
my $newresult = "/home/user/newresults_percengtage_vs_pn";

sub pushval{
        my @fields = @_;
        open OUTFILE, ">>$newresult/fixedhomdata_030716-031316.csv" or die $!;   #line 35
        print OUTFILE "$fields[0]", "$fields[1]","$fields[2]","$fields[3]","$fields[4]","$fields[5]"
        if($fields[5] >= 13) {
              print OUTFILE "0\n";
        } elsif($fields[5] < 13 && $fields[5] > 1) {
              print OUTFILE "1\n";
        } elsif($fields[5] <= 1) {
              print OUTFILE "2\n";
        }

        close (OUTFILE);
```

Comment: i get the following error after fixing my program. Thank yu so much!!

Comment: syntax error at ./reprioritize line 36, near "){"
syntax error at ./reprioritize line 38, near "}elsif"
syntax error at ./reprioritize line 40, near "}elsif"

Comment: I may have missed a semi-colon after the first print statement after the open line.

Comment: it still gives me a no such file or directory exits for the open outfile portion

Comment: maybe if i create the file to be an empty file before hand in the script then do this? because the file doesnt exist since i want to oufile to it.

Comment: like i want it to create a brand new file

Comment: @m.lochhead Does the directory `newresults_percengtage_vs_pn` exist? To be more precise: can you execute `cd /home/user/newresults_percengtage_vs_pn` in a terminal window without errors?

Comment: @PerlDog yes it does exist and i can change directory to it

Comment: @m.lochhead Ok, that's half the battle. I just wanted to make sure.